# Drupal 7 Install on Redhat w/ Apache - sites/default/files is not writable

Tags: linux, drupal, file-permissions

I have spent numerous hours on an issue that has left me puzzled. I am attempting to install Drupal on Linux Redhat using apache, but it will not allow me to pass step 3 due to the fact that sites/default/files is not writable.

I have followed the instructions on Drupal's site, in their install.txt file as well as the instructions of others who have had the same error with no success.

I have granted permissions access all different ways root:root 777, root:apache 777, I have verified that apache is the user running the apache process and I am still stuck.

Note: I was able to complete the install on windows.

Any new ideas?

Comment: Did you already follow the instructions [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)?

Comment: Yes. I have combed their documentation and followed each one step by step, including the one you linked to.

Comment: including setting the owner of the files folder to www-data ?

Comment: My runs as the username apache instead of www-data, but yes I set the folder permissions for that user... even tried 777 with 0 luck. Could a setting in the php.ini affect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after following directions from both official and non-official web sources, the one thing that was never instructed to do or try was to reboot the application AFTER making permission changes to the files directory. I tried it, and this solved the issue.

This is weird because I've never had to reboot an OS after making permission changes on a directory. Additionally I did restart httpd after each change thinking that would be sufficient. Hopefully this can help anyone else running Redhat 7 with the same issue.

Thanks, TH

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the security context of the directory "sites".

My Drupal core files are in: /var/www/html/drupal

Then I applied the command:

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/drupal/sites/